# MySQL Select customer if first entry from 2016

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have a table which stores:

```
id, customerid, amount, date
```

It stores a new row every month for every customer.
I want to select the rows only if the first entry of a customer was in 2016. For example, the first transaction for customerid 1234, amount 49, date 2016-01-01. If this customer had a transaction in 2015, I don't want to select him.

How would I do that? I tried using the min(date) function but it doesn't show me the effect I want.

Comment: No matter what have you tried. Post here

Comment: And what columns do you want to SELECT?

Comment: A simple join will suffice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way (untested):

```
SELECT c.id, c.customerid, c.amount, c.date
  FROM customer
  JOIN (SELECT customerid, MIN(date) AS FirstDate
          FROM customer
      GROUP BY customerid) c2
    ON c2.customerid = c1.customerid
 WHERE c2.FirstDate >= '2016-01-01';
```